# Зачем VAO в OpenGL и какую задачу он выполняет? Зачем мы присваиваем идентификатор объектам OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

1. Зачем VAO в OpenGL и какую задачу он выполняет?
2. Зачем мы присваиваем идентификатор объектам OpenGL?

   ```
   GLuint name_object;
   glGenArrays(1, &name_object)?
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Возьмем простой пример, нужно отрисовать модель. Для этого нам нужно выставить массив координат, текстуры и другие данные. И для этого нужно будет сделать несколько запросов к видеокарте. А мы же хотим рисовать быстро. А ещё можно промазать и активировать левую текстуру. И тут появляются VAO - они позволяют объединить это все в один "пакет" и активировать в один вызов.

И вторая часть вопроса. А зачем присваивать идентификаторы, точнее id. А это такой способ взаимодействия с видеокартой, что бы попросить ее отрисовать данные или как то изменить. Считайте, что это такой себе указатель.